# R - Make a repetitive sequence with 'rep'

Tags: r, rep

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to make a list with, for example 10 '4', 20 '6' and 30 '3' then writing it by hand (`example <- c(4,4,4,4,...)`) with the function 'rep'. I know i can repeat a certain sequence n times and each by n times too, but i don't know how can i make one with different amounts of each number.

Comment: The output i want is: 
"4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3"

Comment: `rep(c(4,6,3), c(10,20,30))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `rep` with both arguments being the desired vectors:

```
x <- rep(c(4, 6, 3), c(10, 20, 30))
table(x)

 3  4  6 
30 10 20
```

Comment: That's it! Don't need the table part but the rest works perfectly. Thank you!!