# R :Looping through each 5 rows of data frame and imputing incremental value

Tags: r, loops, data-munging

I am trying to impute incremental values for each 5 rows of the data frame. I am new to R and not sure how to achieve this.

Input data:

```
state Value 
  a    1
  b    2
  a    3
  c    4
  a    5
  e    6
  f    7
  w    8
  f    9
  s    10
  e    11
  r    12
  s    13
  s    14
```

Desired Output:

```
state Value Increment
  a    1     1
  b    2     1
  a    3     1
  c    4     1
  a    5     1
  e    6     2
  f    7     2
  w    8     2
  f    9     2
  s    10    2
  e    11    3
  r    12    3
  s    13    3
  s    14    3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Make a repetitive sequence with 'rep'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557890/r-make-a-repetitive-sequence-with-rep)

Comment: I get that it's an unclear question, but maybe whoever has downvoted all 5 answers so far could also explain what's wrong with the question and/or answers. For the OP: it's helpful to at least give a clear sense of the logic of what you're trying to do, and include the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your data:

```
df = read.table(text = 
                "state Value 
                     a     1
                     b     2
                     a     3
                     c     4
                     a     5
                     e     6
                     f     7
                     w     8
                     f     9
                     s     10
                     e     11
                     r     12
                     s     13
                     s     14", 
                header=T)
```

You can now use `rownames` to help you to impute the incremental values. The line of code below gives you your desired output, by taking the row indices, dividing them by `5` and then obtaining the `ceiling` (i.e., the closest greater integer).

```
df$Increment <- ceiling(as.numeric(rownames(df))/5)
```

Which will give you your expected output:

```
#    state Value Increment
# 1      a     1         1
# 2      b     2         1
# 3      a     3         1
# 4      c     4         1
# 5      a     5         1
# 6      e     6         2
# 7      f     7         2
# 8      w     8         2
# 9      f     9         2
# 10     s    10         2
# 11     e    11         3
# 12     r    12         3
# 13     s    13         3
# 14     s    14         3
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` solution that checks whether the remainder of dividing the row number minus one with 5 is 0. If it is 0 it increases the value of the new column by 1.

```
dt = read.table(text = 
"state Value 
a    1
b    2
a    3
c    4
a    5
e    6
f    7
w    8
f    9
s    10
e    11
r    12
s    13
s    14", header=T)

library(dplyr)

dt %>% mutate(Increment = cumsum((row_number()-1) %% 5 == 0))

#    state Value Increment
# 1      a     1         1
# 2      b     2         1
# 3      a     3         1
# 4      c     4         1
# 5      a     5         1
# 6      e     6         2
# 7      f     7         2
# 8      w     8         2
# 9      f     9         2
# 10     s    10         2
# 11     e    11         3
# 12     r    12         3
# 13     s    13         3
# 14     s    14         3
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
dt = read.table(text = 
                  "state Value 
a    1
b    2
a    3
c    4
a    5
e    6
f    7
w    8
f    9
s    10
e    11
r    12
s    13
s    14", header=T)

dt$Increment<- unlist(lapply(1:ceiling(nrow(dt)/5), function(x) rep(x, 5) ))[1:nrow(dt)]
dt
```

Comment: does not give desired output

Answer (score 1):

The following function will do what you want.
Arguments:

1. `DF` - the input data.frame;
2. `N`- the number of repeats of each value in the increment;
3. `newcol` - the name of the increment column, defaults to `"Increment"`.

Just assign the result to the new df.

```
fun <- function(DF, N, newcol = "Increment"){
  n <- nrow(DF)
  f <- rep_len(c(1, rep(0, N - 1)), length.out = n)
  DF[[newcol]] <- cumsum(f)
  DF
}

fun(df1, N = 5)
```

**Data.**

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 14
state <- sample(letters, n, TRUE)
Value <- seq_len(n)
df1 <- data.frame(state, Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
rep(c(1:((nrow(df)/5)+1)),
    each=5,
    length.out=dim(df)[1])
```

Which gives:

```
> df$Increment<-rep(c(1:((nrow(df)/5)+1)),
+     each=5,
+     length.out=dim(df)[1])
> df
   state Value Increment
1      a     1         1
2      b     2         1
3      a     3         1
4      c     4         1
5      a     5         1
6      e     6         2
7      f     7         2
8      w     8         2
9      f     9         2
10     s    10         2
11     e    11         3
12     r    12         3
13     s    13         3
14     s    14         3
```

Where `df` is:

```
dt = read.table(text = 
"state Value 
a    1
b    2
a    3
c    4
a    5
e    6
f    7
w    8
f    9
s    10
e    11
r    12
s    13
s    14", header=T)
```